# recompile wpasupplicant Debian package with IPv6 disabled

Tags: debian, package-management, compiling, dpkg

I have a related [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/658943/wpa-supplicant-disable-ipv6), but was asked to open a new one.

I would like to recompile the Debian package `wpasupplicant` with `IPv6` disabled. I know basics of Debian package compilation, ie:

```
apt-get source wpasupplicant
dpkg-buildpackage --build=binary --no-sign
```

What do I have to change, to disable `IPv6` completely?

Also, this particular package seems to want to compile some `qt` versions of wpasuplicant, because the compialtion dependencies ask for `qtbase5-dev` .

Can I compile only the pure/commandline version of `wpasupplicant`, without any gui versions? I don't want to install additional unnecessary dependencies.

I am using Debian 10.

Comment: If you were using Debian 10 your kernel would support IPv6 and you wouldn't have to recompile anything. You can always disable IPv6 on all interfaces in order to have wpa_supplicant not fail there. So are you using a **Debian 10 kernel** too?

Comment: @A.B - I am using custom compiled kernel 5.10.x. And wpasupplicant actually does not fail. It just floods my logs with useless messages

Comment: Reading the sources it fails at setting some filters, like ARP related filters because it bails out at IPv6 filters. Just recompile your kernel and add back IPv6 support, then disable IPv6 use in your network configuration. One less thing to have to regularly recompile

Comment: Btw, depending on why you are compiling your kernel, 5.10 is available in backports: https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/linux-image-amd64  , https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/

Comment: I've been using 5.10, as a backport in a Debian 10 base for months now. No problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example how to compile wpasupplicant posted in [linuxfromscratch](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/wpa_supplicant.html) . To disable IPV6 support you need to remove `CONFIG_IPV6=y` from wpasupplicant build configuration file (`.config`).

You need to install some dependencies:

```
sudo apt install -t buster-backports checkinstall 
sudo apt install desktop-file-utils libxml++2.6-dev qt5-default libssl-dev build-essential  \
libdbus-1-dev libdbus-glib-1-2 libdbus-glib-1-dev libreadline-dev pkg-config dbus \
libncurses5-dev libnl-genl-3-dev libnl-3-dev libreadline-dev
```

Download the tarball from [here](https://w1.fi/releases/)

```
cd /tmp
wget https://w1.fi/releases/wpa_supplicant-2.9.tar.gz
tar xvf wpa_supplicant-2.9.tar.gz
cd wpa_supplicant-2.9/wpa_supplicant
```

Edit your wpasupplicant `.config` file to remove `CONFIG_IPV6=y` then run:

```
make
sudo checkinstall
```

Install the `.deb` using `gdebi` or `apt`.

Comment: This is incorrect. There is no way to disable IPv6 support in wpa_supplicant, and this is the way it should be. wpa_supplicant knows how to work with IPv4 addresses and IPv6 addresses, but support actual OS level support for one or the other is not decided by wpa_supplicant.

The compile flag that GAD3R mentions disables IPv6 support for one of the built-in eapol tests. See the [Makefile](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/wpa_supplicant/Makefile#n1662) for wpa_supplicant.

`ifdef CONFIG_IPV6
# for eapol_test only
CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_IPV6
endif`